# Intent extras lost when back to activity..

Tags: android, android-intent

I have several activites.
Activity A
be startet with:

```
Intent intent_user = new Intent(Friends_Activity.this, UserProfile_Activity.class);
intent_user.putExtra("id", id); //id="1"
startActivity(intent_user);
```

in next, user may call Activity B (in this activity, too, can call Activity A, but "id" is other)

```
Intent intent_user = new Intent(Friends_Activity.this, UserProfile_Activity.class);
intent_user.putExtra("id", id); //id="2"
startActivity(intent_user);
```

And now if i click twice back key, i return in first Activity A, but id is not = 1, id = 2..

How i can save previous value of id??

Sorry for my bad english...

Comment: Use SharedPreferences

Comment: how.. task may be Activity A->B->C->A->B->A and more.. i can not save all value of id..

Comment: I don't know if that is the most elegant way but you could create a Class (eg. a Singleton) where you can globally store all your current ids.

Comment: I dont know how, it have many problems(then +count, then -count) i think it can do whis standard means.. onSaveInstanceState and other..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I created a simple application with three activities: MainActivity (A), TwoActivity (B) and ThreeActivity (C). Default textviews in layout I changed to buttons and changed their values to "main", "2" and "3". flow is A->B->C->B->C->B...

In each onCreate method I added folllowing lines:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, intent.getStringExtra("id"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_three);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent_user = new Intent(ThreeActivity.this,
                    TwoActivity.class); //this is for three activity.
                            //Intent intent_user = new Intent(TwoActivity.this, ThreeActivity.class); //for two activity
                            //Intent intent_user = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TwoActivity.class);//for main activity
            intent_user.putExtra("id", "3"); 
            startActivity(intent_user);

        }
    });
```

When started, first toast is empty, then: B (1), C (2), B(3), C(2), B(3) and so on.

How did you retrieve previous value of id? You can save it via getIntent() and its extras (if it's String, of course).

my test project https://www.dropbox.com/s/e84rub933b5gav7/text.zip

Comment: Yes, if i back, i see old info, but i use pooltoupdate, and id save in static target_id.. if i update this view i have changed id..

Comment: if you save value to the static field, it's one for all instances of that activity. So it has the most recent saved value.